# Что делать , если не хватает полей в плагине?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

Использую плагин для портфолио , но там не хватает полей. К примеру автор , описание, время ... Как вообще выходить из таких ситуациях , когда не хватает полей ?Просто не у одного плагина нету всех нужных мне полей. Автор , описание, кнопка читать далее , дата, картинка...

Comment: почитайте о custom fields в wordpress

Comment: Обычно у плагинов есть свой внутренний API для расширения и поля добавляются хуками, как это реализовано в WooCommerce. Или при помощи ACF. Название плагина хоть покажите

Comment: @mihdan *обычно* у плагинов нет никого АПИ. ;) WC и ещё несколько крупняков тут скорее исключение.

Comment: разве ACF можно добавлять в плагины ? Portfolio Gallery – Image Gallery WordPress Plugin

Comment: Просто не в одном плагине не хватает нужных мне полей

Comment: @XXXXXX  [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) ты добавляешь не "к плагину", а к конечной сущности (посту, странице, таксономии и тд)

Comment: это я понимаю , но потом плагин сам эти поля не сможет вывести. Следовательно надо зайти в файл плагина  и там добавить код  для вывода полей ?

Comment: ACF вполне легально подключается к теме или плагину - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-within-a-plugin-or-theme/ @XXXXXX

Comment: Не стоит использовать плагины, которые нет возмоожности расширять, хотелки у клиента всегда будут @SeVlad

Comment: Для внесения ясносности ACF: Advanced Custom Fields - это плагин для добавления произвольных полей к сущностям WordPress.

Comment: @mihdan Ты меня порой удивляешь :) Сам же разработчик, а иногда как что скажешь - как с другой планеты :)

Comment: @XXXXXX это смотря какой плагин и что как делает. Универсальных рецептов нет. Если функция вывода проверяется на существование, то можно её переопределить в теме или своём плагине. А если нет, то плохо. Хотя тоже могут быть варианты.. вплоть до рисование в DOM.

Comment: Я вас всех понял , спасибо за советы )